# Using waitForKeyElements with MutationObserver : Callback-Function for access data in iframe only works with full page-reload

Tags: javascript, userscripts, mutation-observers

I use the following code to access a field (var addInfo) in an iframe via userscript in tampermonkey. The code currently works when the page is fully reloaded. However, it does not work if waitForKeyElements is triggered a second time by the MutationObserver. The MutationObserver itself works and would call the function, but it is not executed. What could be the reason?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         _Wait for delayed or AJAX page load
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @match        https://urlFromPage/*
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require      https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a major design
    change introduced in GM 1.0.
    It restores the sandbox.
*/
/* global $, waitForKeyElements */






// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
const targetNode = document.getElementById("content");;

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
    for (const mutation of mutationList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
            

        } else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
            console.log(`The ${mutation.attributeName} attribute was modified.`);
        }
    }
    
    waitForKeyElements('#content > div > div > article', actionFunction, true, '#content > iframe');

};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);






function actionFunction() {
    var frame = document.querySelector("#content > iframe");
    var frameDoc = frame.contentDocument;
    var body = frameDoc.getElementsByTagName("body");
   
    var addInfo = frameDoc.getElementsByTagName("div")[25].innerHTML;
   

    if (addInfo != null) {
        alert(addInfo);
    }

    observer.disconnect();

}
```

Comment: You use a different selector inside the iframe when waiting ('#content > div > div > article') and when reading, which probably means that they correspond to different elements. Note that actionFunction is already called with the found nodes so no need to find them manually - just make sure that the first selector is correct in both scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because a separate HTML element with nested elements was created for each opened object. So i had to determine the active element in advance and access the required field in it